# is implicit downcasting using new OK?

Tags: c++, inheritance, new-operator, derived-class, downcast

What do you think of this piece of C++ code :

```
Polygon* p;
if(shape=="Rectangle")
    p = new Rectangle();
else if(shape=="Triangle")
    p = new Triangle();
else
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

where Rectangle and Triangle derive from a base-class Polygon.

The idea behind it is that I need to use specific methods from the derived classes without knowing which class I need until the program runs.
Is there a better way of doing this? It compiles but I wonder if the destructor of the selected derived-class is called so the specific variables are properly freed.

Subsidiary question : does a dynamic_cast operation involve a data copy?

Thanks :)

**EDIT:**

Thank you for all these very instructive answers.

Now let's say the method

```
bool isIsosceles()
```

is implemented in Triangle but not in Rectangle.

Then calling right away

```
p->isIsosceles()
```

would obviously fail.

My first ideas would be either:

Declare and implement isIsosceles() as virtual method in base-class Polygon as

```
virtual bool isIsosceles()
{ 
    cout << "Isosceles means nothing to me." << endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

or the use of dynamic_cast in an if statement.

Is any of these options a good practice here ?

Many thanks

Comment: _"Is there a better way of doing this?"_ Yes, use smart pointers instead of doing the memory management with `new()` and  `delete` yourself. Also I would recommend to put this code in a designated factory class, that's responsible to create the correct types.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` does not involve a data copy, but it does involve the use of run time type information (RTTI). It is frequently considered a slow operation.

Answer (score 2):

> Is implicit downcasting using new OK?

There is no "downcasting" going on here: this is a straightforward use of polymorphic behavior. Your `Polygon *` is a pointer to a base class; your construction code produces an object that abstracts out implementation through the use of virtual member functions.

> It compiles but I wonder if the destructor of the selected derived-class is called so the specific variables are properly freed.

Provided that the destructor in the base class is virtual (which it should be) freeing the object through the base class pointer will do everything correctly:

```
delete p;
```

> Is there a better way of doing this?

You could use [`std::unique_ptr<Polygon>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) to automate the process of deleting your `Polygon` object. Using a smart pointer would destroy the object when the pointer goes out of scope.

> Does a `dynamic_cast` operation involve a data copy?

I am assuming that you do not have a use for `dynamic_cast` here, because `Polygon` declares virtual member functions for all operations of interest. However, when you do `dynamic_cast`, there is no data copying going on. The system checks if the cast is allowed, and either gives you a properly cast pointer, or returns a `nullptr`.

Answer (score 1):

Will work if you remember to `delete p` and the destructor of `Polygon` is `virtual`. This is vital.

A better alternative is wrapping it up in a smart pointer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not downcasting. You're actually using polymorphism here, i.e. creating object of some derived type that you will use as an object of their base type.

You can do that, but as with everything that you allocate with new, use delete. Another thing to note is that you need a virtual destructor in `Polygon`, like that:

```
class Polygon {

    virtual ~Polygon();
}
```

otherwise you'll end up with object slicing, that is you will have objects "half-deleted".

Additional note: FYI, downcasting would be, using your classes, doing the following:

```
Polygon* polygon = new Triangle();

Triangle* triangle = dynamic_cast<Triangle*>(polygon);

// Check that we effectively had a triangle under this polygon pointer
if(triangle){
     //do something with the triangle
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The idea behind it is that I need to use specific methods from the derived classes without knowing which class I need until the program runs.

That kind of defeats the purpose of polymorphism, which allows you to perform operations WITHOUT knowing what derived type you are working with.

> Is there a better way of doing this?

That depends on what you are actually trying to accomplish in the first place.  What you have shown can be implemented as part of a class factory, for instance.  Bu you have not shown how you are using those objects after creating them, so it is hard to say whether you are doing the right thing or not.

> I wonder if the destructor of the selected derived-class is called so the specific variables are properly freed.

It will only if `~Polygon()` is declared as `virtual`.

> does a dynamic_cast operation involve a data copy?

No.  A `dynamic_cast` is simply performing a runtime lookup to obtain a pointer to a different section of the VMT for the same object.